# How to split a directory containing N folders in 2 directories containing N/2 folders each

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory which contains 50.0000 folders. I want to split it into 2 directories. Each directory will contain 25.0000 folders.

How can I do it in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the folders using

`os.walk("/path/to/folders")`

iterate over the first half of the folders contained in the root folder and use `shutil.move("directory_to_move","destination_directory")` to move the "directory_to_move" into "destination_directory"

you will have to import both the `os` module and `shutil`

Checkout [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) and [os.walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) for guidance.